# Dataclass that can 'yeld' a new line from a file when requested

Tags: python-3.x

With something like the following code I've used until now to create a generator that would read a very big file line by line and allow me to work on each line as I wish.

```
def readfile(self):
    with open(self.filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            yield line
```

What would be a good way to edit this so as to get the new line every time I am calling a function, e.g.:

```
@dataclass
class Reader:
    filename: str
    line: int = field(default=None)

def __post_init__(self):
    self.file = open(self.filename)
    self.line = 1

def __del__(self):
    self.file.close()

def next_line(self):
    ...
```

So ideally I would call `next_line` and get back the next line of file `filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you want to create a class just to call a method that returns the next line of a file so I created just a function. If you need to, you can use it as a method in some class as well.

A file object IS already a generator. Therefore you can call the `__next()__` method directly on the file object. `__next__()` returns the next value of a generator.

```
def next_line():
    return f.__next__()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(next_line())      # a line
    second = next_line()    # next line
    print(next_line())      # next line
```

Or you can even omit the function completely:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(f.__next__())      # a line
    second = f.__next__()    # next line
    print(f.__next__())      # next line
```

Comment: I want to hold a number of metrics and do some additional operations on the background that is why I want to build a class

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You can use this example in your class as well.